# What should I do when SSH on Ubuntu freezes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty

When I'm using SSH to connect to an Ubuntu machine and it freezes, I'd just close PuTTY and re-login.

Is there a better way to handle errors like this? (like Ctrl+Alt+Del in Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to work via SSH is to run a terminal multiplexer like screen.  SSH in like normal, launch a screen session.  If you drop your connection just SSH back in and reattach to the already running session. Screen also allows you to share a session, split your screen multiple times and detach a session and reconnect, with your programs still as you left them.

If your SSH process is locking up, or something else, then you have a larger problem then I am addressing.

Here is some more info on using screen.  [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Screen).

Answer (score 0):

Justin S makes a great recommendation. As an alternative you might want to consider trying out autossh. It automatically reconnects when an SSH tunnel breaks.